# ShellAndWait alternative?

Tags: vba, outlook

I've written a macro to automate some trivial tasks with my Outlook mailboxes. One of these tasks is to execute a bash script on a remote server. This code works fine, however I really require the exit code passed from the execution of the script. I have tried the ShellAndWait approach over here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ShellAndWait.aspx which turned out to be problematic.

It seems too heavy. Is there a simpler approach?

This is a snippet from my code:

```
If result = True Then
    retval = Shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"" -ssh ME@MYSERVER -m "myCmds.bat", vbNormalFocus)
    MsgBox "Retval: " & retval, vbInformation
End If
```

The return values I am getting in `retval` are like 5406, or 7968 for example. Which btw, are these even meaningful? What do they represent?

Comment: the return value from Shell is nothing to do with any return value from plink.exe. It is the task id of the instance of plink.exe Shell started. A (slightly) lighter weight approach you could try is to make myCmds.bat create a temp file as its first line, then delete it when finished. You can then have a loop with Sleep in it and test if the temp file 'indicator' has been deleted. However, what is wrong with just shoving ShellAndWait into a class? That is what a class is for - it encapsulates robust but longer code into an easy interface.

Comment: Hmm, another approach is to poll in a loop (with a small sleep) to see if the task id (you stored from calling Shell) is still running using an approach similar to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d4a10166-8eac-40e5-bd48-d3eb22e3642e/checking-to-see-is-a-program-has-completed-by-taskid?forum=accessdev

Comment: In `myCmds.bat` is something to the effect of `~/myScript.sh myParameter`. At the server side, bash executes this. I am after the exit code of this script run on the server, so it is irrelevant for me to use the task ID of the shell function stored in `retval`. So the question remains: how can I pass this exit code back to the VBA macro? I do not understand the shellAndWait() class linked above. So I'm only going to go through the headache of using it if I absolutely must.

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a reference to the Windows Shell and using [WShell.Run](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5fk67ky%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)? Go to Tools--->References and check the box next to "Windows Scripting Host Object Model".

You can then run code like the following:

```
Public Sub Test()
    Dim wsh As WshShell
    Set wsh = New WshShell
    Debug.Print wsh.Run("ping www.google.com", vbNormalFocus, True) 'Waits for ping to finish, then displays the exit code.
End Sub
```

Comment: Question: If I use this approach but the same command as I've passed to Shell in my code provided above, will this return the exit code of plink or the bash script run on the server? Because the latter is what I'm really after.

Comment: It would be the exit code of plink most likely. Instead you might try piping the output of the bash script to a file, wait until the shell command is finished running, then open the file to see the results. How would you expect to see the results if you ran this command manually from your command prompt?

Comment: The script runs an SSH connection to a router and will output "reboot successful" or "timeout error" to a log file in my server's home directory so I use this for granularity. However, the script returns exit codes and these are what I intended to use to control my VBA on my local machine to do other stuff <b>locally</b>. But as I cannot do this what you have linked me is worth a try. However since I am running commands on the server from a local batch file `myCmds.bat` I think the server will direct the SSH output to a file on the server which is not useful...

Comment: ... If I am to give what you have linked a try, the output needs to be saved on the machine local to plink so that I can open the file with VBA and regex on something unique like "XYX" which I can code into my script to echo back on success (`exit 0`), however I don't see this directing remote output to a temporary file locally to the VBA macro. I may be wrong?